# flockdb setup failed

Tags: twitter, graph-databases, querulous, flockdb

I built twitter's graph-databases flockdb successfully. But when I run script 'setup-env.sh' under dist/flockdb/scripts, I got the following errors(from development.log):

```
INF [20120807-19:01:36.635] stats: Starting LatchedStatsListener
INF [20120807-19:01:36.684] admin: Admin HTTP interface started on port 9990.
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous: Error initially populating pool localhost
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.twitter.querulous.database.ThrottledPoolingDatabase.mkConnection(ThrottledPoolingDatabase.scala:266)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.twitter.querulous.database.ThrottledPoolingDatabase$$anonfun$5.apply(ThrottledPoolingDatabase.scala:229)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.twitter.querulous.database.ThrottledPoolingDatabase$$anonfun$5.apply(ThrottledPoolingDatabase.scala:229)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.twitter.querulous.database.ThrottledPool.addObject(ThrottledPoolingDatabase.scala:67)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.twitter.querulous.database.ThrottledPool$$anonfun$1.apply$mcVI$sp(ThrottledPoolingDatabase.scala:58)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at scala.collection.immutable.Range$ByOne$class.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:285)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at scala.collection.immutable.Range$$anon$2.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:265)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.twitter.querulous.database.ThrottledPool.<init>(ThrottledPoolingDatabase.scala:58)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     at com.twitter.querulous.database.ThrottledPoolingDatabase.<init>(ThrottledPoolingDatabase.scala:229)
WAR [20120807-19:01:37.277] querulous:     (...more...)
```

This seems to be some problem caused by querulous. Could anyone give me some advice on how to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Compile is not completed. You could remove all the cache of sbt and then recompile the Flockdb. The cache directory usually is `/root/.ivy2`, remove `.ivy2` directory. It will work for you.